# SAGA does not work in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga

I have installed QGIS 3.28, but only the SAGA Plugin does not work at all, however it worked earlier in old QGIS stable version. Now it does not even work in the old version too. Always says

> The following layers were not correctly generated

How can I use fill sinks?

[image]